# Fetch API working with non HTTP-Scheme using Electron but not using CEF

Tags: c++, cors, electron, fetch, chromium-embedded

I'm writing an application with HTML5 frontend and C++ backend. I want to use a custom scheme ("klaes://") to communicate between the frontend and the backend. I already tried using ElectronJS in combination with navtive c++-addons to solve these requirements, **which worked just fine**.

Now I'm trying to solve the same requiremnts using Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF). Everything works fine, except that I'm not able to use the Fetch-API on my custom-scheme.

**In Electron I did following:**

Register custom Scheme

```
protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged ([{
    scheme: "klaes",
    privileges: {
        supportFetchAPI: true,
        "corsEnabled": true
    }
}])
```

Handle Requests:

```
protocol.registerBufferProtocol ("klaes", (request, callback) => {
   // ...
}
```

everything worked fine here.

**In CEF I tried following:**

Register custom scheme:

```
class ClientSchemeHandler : public CefResourceHandler { 

  // handle request
  bool ProcessRequest(CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
    CefRefPtr<CefCallback> callback) OVERRIDE {
    // ...  
 }

 // add CORS header
 void GetResponseHeaders(CefRefPtr<CefResponse> response,
            int64& response_length,
            CefString& redirectUrl) OVERRIDE {
   // ...
   response->GetHeaderMap(hdrMap);
   hdrMap.insert(std::make_pair ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"));
   response->SetHeaderMap(hdrMap);
   // ...
 }

};

class ClientSchemeHandlerFactory : public CefSchemeHandlerFactory {
  // ...
};
```

Within my App I did:

```
void SimpleApp::OnContextInitialized() {

  // ...

  CefRegisterSchemeHandlerFactory("klaes", "openmodule", new ClientSchemeHandlerFactory ());


  // ...

  // Browsersettings
  CefBrowserSettings browser_settings;
  browser_settings.web_security = STATE_DISABLED;


}
```

Set the fetch_enabled - Flag for the given scheme

```
void SimpleApp::OnRegisterCustomSchemes(CefRawPtr<CefSchemeRegistrar> registrar) {
  registrar->AddCustomScheme("klaes",  CEF_SCHEME_OPTION_FETCH_ENABLED);
}
```

Requests without fetch-API (like imgs, script, href, etc.) works fine. **BUT**
when I try a fetch-Request I got the following frontend error:
`Fetch API cannot load klaes://openmodule/5. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.", source: klaes://openmodule/www/build/p-elph9ath.entry.js (1)`

I get the same error within ElectronJS when I uncomment the `"corsEnabled": true` option for `registerSchemesAsPrivileged`

Did I any mistake or is it simply not possible with CEF but possible with Electron?

By the way I used the **07/25/2019 - CEF 75.1.8+g84fed5d+chromium-75.0.3770.100 / Chromium 75.0.3770.100** build for Windows.

Comment: I tried a lot of ```cef_scheme_options_t``` combinations, but none of them solved the problem. Thanks to @gjha for his reply, but this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Following code should fix your issue:

```
void SimpleApp::OnRegisterCustomSchemes(CefRawPtr<CefSchemeRegistrar> registrar) {
  registrar->AddCustomScheme("klaes",  CEF_SCHEME_OPTION_FETCH_ENABLED|CEF_SCHEME_OPTION_CORS_ENABLED);
}
```

Also you can play with options available in `enum` `cef_scheme_options_t` [here](https://github.com/chromiumembedded/cef/blob/c3c3af34fd72434cd71f4d1573841bc88d182218/include/internal/cef_types.h#L2836)

Comment: Sorry, does not work. Same issue. I should have mentioned, that I tried a lot of  ```cef_scheme_options_t``` combinations ...